# Stored procedure will not return OUT var

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm a nubee to stored procedures and the below has got me puzzled.
It seems that the @Status variable is not being SET?

When I call the query it runs fine but returns null.
I'm calling using:

```
call new_customer1('Someone@someemail.com', @Status);
SELECT @Status;
```

SP Query follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE new_customer1(
IN CusEmail VARCHAR(75),
OUT Status TINYINT(2)
)
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT Email FROM customers WHERE Email = @CusEmail)
THEN SET @Status = 1;
ELSE
# Perform inssert
SET @Status = 0;
END IF;
END $$
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the responses Velko and Drew.  So it seems that my query is okay.  However I'm still getting a return of NULL where you seem to get the desired results of 1 or 0?  Any ideas?

Comment: It is important to indicate the difference between [9.4 User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) and routine parameters [13.1.12 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html), are different variables. In your stored procedure `OUT \`Status\` != @\`Status\``.

Answer (score 1):

### Schema

```
create table customers
(  id int auto_increment primary key,
   email varchar(100) not null
);

insert customers (email) values ('trump@trump.com');
```

### Stored Proc

```
drop procedure if exists new_customer1;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE new_customer1(IN CusEmail VARCHAR(75), OUT NewStatus TINYINT(2))
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT Email FROM customers WHERE Email = CusEmail) THEN 
        SET NewStatus = 1;
    ELSE
        SET NewStatus = 0;
    END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

### Test

```
call new_customer1('notthere',@theOut);
select @theOut; -- 0
call new_customer1('trump@trump.com',@theOut);
select @theOut; -- 1
```

Comment: I think this works fine. Sorry for stepping on code @velko

Comment: Hahah :) No problem I think it looks better now :)